# Archive submission failed 'MainWindow～iphone.nib'was not found

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I want to update my iPad application but face some error like this.
How to fixed?

Nib File 'MainWindow～iphone.nib'was not found.Please ensure the specified file is included in the bundle with any required device modifiers appended to the filename.

Comment: did you check your build phase?

Comment: I don't have that file in build phase, because my App design for iPad.